# Is $\{\varphi f | f \in H^\infty\}$ a closed ideal in $H^\infty$ if $\varphi$ is inner?

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\varphi$ be an inner function. Is $J=\{\varphi f | f \in H^\infty\}$ a closed ideal in $H^\infty$? I don't know how to get a start with this question. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need the Blaschke part of $\phi$ to be non trivial (equivalently) $\phi$ to have at least one zero in the open disc as otherwise you get the whole space

Comment: @Conrad, Can you explain more if $\phi$ has at least one zero in the open unit disc $D$?